# How many different positive integers are divisors of N?

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading a book on combinatorics and one of the exercise questions asks:

**Suppose a positive integer N factors as $p_{1}^{n_1}.p_{2}^{n_2}...p_{m}^{n_m}$ where $p_1, p_2, ..., p_m$ are distinct prime numbers and $n_1, n_2,..., n_m$ are positive integers. How many different positive integers are divisors of N?**

I thought of writing the prime factors separately:

$$p_1p_1p_1...p_1{\times}p_2p_2...p_2{\times}p_3...p_mp_m...p_m$$

Then for each of the p's you could choose to include it or not include it, giving a count of:

$$2^{n_1+n_2+...+n_m}$$

But this is of course overcounting it since, if I chose 2 $p_1$'s, I could have chosen any two from the $n_1$ $p_1$'s and it would result in the same number.

How do I proceed from here?

Thank you.

EDIT: Questions answered in the comment. 
Answer is $(n_1+1)(n_2+1)...(n_m+1)$ since one can chose to include between 0 to $n_i$ instances of the $i^{th}$ prime.

Comment: The answer is $\left(n_1+1\right)\left(n_2+1\right)\cdots \left(n_m+1\right)$.

Comment: Nevermind, the comment below cleared it. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of choosing wether to choose a given factor $p$, consider that for every prime factor $p_i$, you can choose how many times you take it, between $0$ and $n_i$. What does that give you?

Comment: @Arnaud Got it, thanks!